# I dual boot operating systems. Is there a free way I can rename one of the boot options at startup?

Tags: operating-systems

I dual boot operating systems. Is there a free way I can rename one of the boot options at startup? For example, if a boot option is "Windows", could I rename it to "Windows XP" somehow?

Comment: What kind of OSes are you dualbooting? And what kind of bootmngr is running?

Comment: Knowing what your bootloader is would help. If you're running multiple Windows versions, most likely you're using Window's bootloader and can often change settings within windows to change the naming convention in the boot loader. Other like Grub or Lilo can just as easily be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several programs that could do this for you. If we're talking about Windows 7, I'd suggest trying [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) out; it's free-as-in-beer, pretty intuitive, and lets you manage everything about the Windows 7/Vista bootloader. If you want free-as-in-speech, I'd take a look at [installing GRUB for windows](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/Howto_Boot_Grub_from_windows); it's the open-source standard bootloader, and is very configurable (though not quite as easy to learn as EasyBCD).

If it is just the XP default bootloader you can edit this information in the boot ini file, either manually or use My Computer Properties > Advanced Tab > Startup and Recovery Settings button > System Startup "edit", be careful what you edit in that file. Back it up before you edit it.